# CodeDOM - Unsupported 16-bit application

Tags: vb.net, compilation, output, codedom, 16-bit

I've been using CodeDOM in VB.NET for a long time, but this is first time I am getting this weird error :

*Unsupported 16-bit Application
The program or feature "path" cannot start or run due to the incompatibility with 64-bit version of windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit windows compatible version is available.*

Builder works fine, while CodeDOM compiled application doesn't.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.

CodeDOM code is just a simple messagebox, so I doubt it's related to this problem.

Comment: My crystal ball says that it is time to cleanup your TEMP directory.  You can get a fact instead of a guess by using SysInternals' Process Monitor utility, it shows you which file is being found.

Comment: @Hans Passant How's that going to fix my problem? I don't understand.